# SQL Filtering a date grabbing column and having it grab 10 days previous of record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to figure out how to query a database and go back 10 days from a certain date column. I am using SQL Server 2012.

```
Where Date_Complete IS (10 days ago or newer)
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean this

```
WHERE Date_Complete >= DATEADD(day,-10, yourdatecolumn)
```

If you want to consider the time from today then it'd be

```
WHERE Date_Complete >= DATEADD(day,-10, GETDATE())
```

Comment: 10 days from today is the future, but your question says otherwise

Comment: Refer this for better understanding: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp

Comment: Then `yourdatecolumn` becomes `GETDATE()`